# Delete Multiple Items from HomeDirectory

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I want to delete multiple items from my HomeDirectory.

I'm using `UICollectionView` with `allowsMultipleSeletion = YES;`

After that I save `NSIndexPath` of selected items in `NSMutableArray`.

I'm trying to use this code

```
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/Photos/"]

NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaulManager]

NSString *result = [path stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@"[manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

[manager removeItemsAtPath:result];
```

The problem is how do I pass `NSIndexPath` in Array on `objectAtIndex`?

Comment: instead of `stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", anotherString` use `stringByAppendingString:anotherString` - don't waste processor time. Even better, use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` - don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi here is your code

```
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/Photos/"]

NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaulManager]

for(NSIndexPath *indexPath in array)
{

       NSString *result = [path stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@"[manager  contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        

    [manager removeItensAtPath:result];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `item` property to get the item index out of a `NSIndexPath`.